# Spring mvc result page and back browser button

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc

On my MVC spring application I send a form to a page using post method to perform a search with some parameters. The results of the search is a list and, for every entry is possible to navigate to a details page. It works fine but, when an user try to come back to result page with back browser button (or a Javascript), I get an "Expire page" error. Refreshing the page, it rexecutes the post submit and it works fine.

To prevent this error I added

```
response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
```

to the search controller and everything works fine with Safari and Firefox but I get the same "Expire page" error when I try to execute the web application with IE (8 and 9).

What's the right way to go to a detail page and come back without getting any error?

thanks for your time!
Andrea

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The right way is to use GET instead of POST: searching is an idempotent operation which doesn't cause any change on the server, and such operations should be done with a GET.

Answer (score 2):

Not expiring a POST request seems to undermine [the very idea of a POST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POST_%28HTTP%29):

> Per RFC 2616, the POST method should be used for any context in which a request is non-idempotent: that is, it causes a change in server state each time it is performed, such as submitting a comment to a blog post or voting in an online poll.

Instead, I would restructure how you view the detail records, maybe with an overlay `DIV` that doesn't refresh the underlying page that shows the results.  With many modern web apps, using the BACK button can cause issues with page flow.

Comment: I understand your point of view and basically I'm agree but, in that case, I need to refactor a big part of application. Is there a way to resubmit the value every time I come back to my page? (I.e. storing the form parameters on session? With @ModelAttribute seems not be possible to do that

Comment: If that's the case, your on-page back button shouldn't just go back 1 in the history; instead grab the params in your handler method and add them back in to the `Model` so that you can send them back to the JSP to be reused.  The the back button can be a submit of the old form.